# Javascript/Jquery : how we can prevent execution of other code until form submission done

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
document.myForm.submit();
window.dialogArguments.close();
```

`dialogArguments.close()` line is getting executed first and `document.myForm.submit()` line is getting executed last.

How can we stop the interpeter to execute other lines of code until substitution done?

Comment: I am thinking to have some call back method which will execute after form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You should not prevent any part of code. Just need put your code in right place.

For example:

```
function deleteDocument(form) {
    if (confirm("Do you really want to delete the document?")) 
       form.submit();
       window.dialogArguments.close();
   }

<form action="deleteDocument.php" onsubmit="deleteDocument(this);return false;">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
document.myForm.submit();
setTimeout(
    function() {
      window.dialogArguments.close();    },
 500);
```

Set time out for delay execute for function.
                 or 
Use as callback function to window.dialogArguments.close() ;

Comment: This is like jugar. is there any right way to do same.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form onsubmit="do_something()">

     function do_something(){
      // Do your stuff here
     }
```

If you put return like the code below, you can prevent the form submission by returning false from the do_something() function.

```
    <form onsubmit="return do_something()">

     function do_something(){
    // Do your stuff here
    return true; // submit the form

    return false; // don't submit the form
   }
```